# Getting access to the inner object of a json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using Ant Design framework for my react project. I want to get access to the inner object "quote.USD.price" and put it on the dataSource array but unfortunately, I don't know how.
[image: inner object value access]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you are looking for something like this. You can access inner fields of objects in any of the below methods

```js
const crypto = {
  quote: {
    USD: {
      price: 10
    }
  }

}

const data1 = {
  title: "price",
  dataIndex: crypto.quote.USD.price,
  key: "id"
}

const data2 = {
  title: "price",
  dataIndex: crypto["quote"]["USD"]["price"],
  key: "id"
}


console.log(data1)
console.log(data2)
//both should output the same
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you 
Yeah I just saw in their documentation "Besides, the breaking change is changing dataIndex from nest string path like user.age to string array path like ['user', 'age']"

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to parse a string that is concatenated with dots that represents the location of a value inside some nested objects.

I wrote a utility function to recursively does that. You can see it in action in [**this React project**](https://codesandbox.io/s/find-value-in-an-object-by-concatenated-string-keys-m8r9k). I did it with TypeScript but you can remove the type annotations.

```
const findPriceByMultipleKeys = (dataKey: string, data: any): string | number => {
  let keys: string[] = dataKey.split(".");
  // If dataKey is one key without any dot notation, return the value
  if(keys.length === 1) return data[dataKey];

  let key: string = "";
  let keysRest: string[] = [];

  if (keys.length) {
    // get first element from keys
    // capture the rest of the keys
    [key, ...keysRest] = keys;
  }
  // Check if there any more indexes left to evaluate
  if (keysRest.length) {
    // Transform keysRest to string concatenated with dots
    let keysRestStr = keysRest.join(".");
    // Let the function call itself to go deeper in the object with
    // the remaining indexes and objects
    return findPriceByMultipleKeys(keysRestStr, data[key]);
  } else {
    // If no keys left to evaluate, return the value
    return data[key];
  }
};
```